# Why do I get exploding grad problem even with ResNet, Batchnorm, ReLU? (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I've devised a simple sythentic data

```
tempdataset = np.random.normal(0.0,1.0,[20,10])
templabelset = np.random.normal(0.0,1.0,[20,10])
```

so there would be 20 training examples and the NN input will have the size of 10

I've implemented a simple 10 layers deep ResNet with batchnorm, ReLu activations

```
def resnet_block(self, input_data, num_nodes):
    temp = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=num_nodes)(input_data)
    temp = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(temp)
    temp2 = tf.keras.layers.Add()([input_data, temp])
    temp3 = tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(temp2)
    return temp3

def create_model(self):

    network = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,tf.keras.activations.relu)(self.input_vec)
    network = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(network)

    for i in range(0, 10):
        network = self.resnet_block(network, 10)

    network = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, tf.keras.activations.linear)(network)

    return network

def optimize(self, dataset, labelset, ln, epoch):

    cost = tf.reduce_mean((self.network - self.label_vec)**2)

    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(ln).minimize(cost)

    for i in range(epoch):

        _, loss = self.session.run([train_step, cost], feed_dict={self.input_vec: dataset, self.label_vec: labelset})

        print(' current epoch ', i, ' and loss at ' , loss)
```

here, the self.input_vec is a tf.placeholder

and then if I were to optimize it via

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    NN = ResNet(..... constructors initialization.....)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    NN.optimize(tempdataset,templabelset,0.01,10000)
```

I quickly get loss explode into infinity.

I've tried every permutations of (BN, ReLU, Add), for example (Add -> Batch -> ReLU)

and it still gives me exploding loss.

The problem is that sometimes, it's fine and does minimize the loss, but sometimes, the loss explodes.

Comment: What `initializer` are you using? Try with different initializers.

Comment: Which learning rate are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have too few examples. Try with hundreds of examples and lower learning rate. 
Also try different optimizer, like Adam or Adadelta.